# Work to provide explanation on the definition of the area of a Jordan-measurable set

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

The problem is as follows:

> **Given this theorem:**
>
> Let $D$ be bounded & Jordan-measurable set
>
> Let $f$ be a bounded function on $D$
>
> And $f$ is continuous except for a set of zero area
>
> Then the conclusion is that the $\int\int _D f$ exists
>
> and $\int\int_D f$ = $\int\int_R F$ where $F$ takes values $f(p)$ if
>   the point $p$ is in D, and $0$ otherwise.
>
> **Goal:**  To use this theorem to explain why for a Jordan-measurable set, I can say that the area $A(D) = \int\int _D 1 dA$

So far, I have several ideas coming to mind, but I don't see how my ideas have anything to do with the explanation that they are looking for >"<

**My thoughts:**

**(1)** A region $D$ is Jordan-measurable if the region has definite area

**(2)** In other context, $D$ is Jordan-measurable means that I can find a polygon which is totally inside $D$, and also another polygon such that this polygon contains the previous polygon, thus this "new" polygon contains some boundary points of $D$

**(3)** Another idea about $D$ is that $bdy(D)$ has zero area

**(4)** From the theorem and using the fact that the function $f = 1$ clearly is bounded on $D$ and continuous except for a set of zero area, then the double integral of $f=1$ over region $D$ exists and can also be transfered to a double integral of $F$ over rectangle $R$, by how F is defined in the theorem.

But I don't see the connection.

Well, consider only $A(D) = \int\int _D 1 dA$, then my understanding is that for $dA = dxdy$ or $dA = dydx$, when I do the double integral over region $D$ with respect to this change of area, what I'm doing is to "cover" region $D$ by two rectangles, one with respect to $x$ (call it U) and one with respect to $y$ (call it V).

So I think the idea of (2) comes here since I'm trying to find such 2 polygons.  (3) also holds trivially.  Together with how $F$ is defined, which is basically accepting the function value of point $p$ if it's in the set $D$, and discard the function value of $p$ if it isn't in the set.  Then, as conclusion, the area A(D) is the sum of the two rectangles U and V?

Would someone please help me on this question? I'm a bit lost >_>

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is $A(D) = \iint_D 1$ a *definition* or a *theorem* that you want to prove? I.e. are you looking for an *explanation* why calling $\iint_D 1$ the area of $D$ is sensible, or are you attempting to *prove* that the area (as defined for jordan-measurable sets) is indeed equal to $\iint_D 1$?

Comment: @fgp  My book didn't say it's a definition or a theorem, it just prompts the fact out of nowhere. But from my old Calculus book, it states this as a property.  I think the question is asking for why I can express the double integral in such way being A(D), using the idea in the provided theorem @_@

Comment: Ok, I wrote an answer. Whether it answers your question or not I do not know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what the actual question *is*, but I'll try to give an answer nevertheless.

First, a matter of notation. Usually, an integral of $f$ over some set $M$ (no matter in how many dimensions) is written simply as $\int_M f\,d\mu$, where $\mu$ indicates the measure that is to be used. For pure riemann integrals, just writing $\int_M f$ suffices, because there really one is one possible measure. I'm guessing that $\int \int_M f\,dA$ is simply supposed to mean $\int_M f$, i.e. the integral of $f$ over $M$.

Since the question doesn't include a *definition* of $A(D)$ other than $A(D) = \int_D 1$, I also asumme that what's wanted here is an *explanation* why that integral yields the area of $D$, rather than a formal proof (which would first require a definition of what the area of $D$ is supposed to be).

Remember that the definite integral of a positive function $f$ in *one* dimension between $a$ and $b$ is simply the area under the curve $f(x)$ between the two lines $x=a$ and $x=b$. In two dimensions, the same holds, but you can pick more complicated shapes. In other words, for a positive $f$ and $D \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, the integral $\int_D f$ is the volume of the set $$
  S := \left\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \,:\, (x,y) \in D, 0 \leq z \leq f(x,y)\right\} \text{.}
$$

Now, if $f(x)$ is constant on $D$, i.e. $f(x)=c$, then $V$ is simply $D \times [0,c]$ (For example, if $D$ is a circle, $V$ is a disc with height $c$). In that case, you thus have that $$
  A_3(S) = A_2(D) \cdot c \text{.}
$$
where $A_3$ measures volumes in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $A_2$ measures areas in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

If in particular $c=1$, i.e. if $f(x)=1$, then $A_3(S) = A_2(D)$. Since $A_3(S) = \int_D 1$ it follows that $$
  A_2(D) = \int_D 1 \text{.}
$$

I hope all this formalism doesn't distract from the simply geometric idea behind this. If you take some shape, and look at the volume between that shape at the constant function $1$, then this volume is the area of the shape times 1.